# How to get the mouse pos relative to the background img

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I need to get the mouse position on a divs background img.

This is the css:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;   
background-image: url("default.png");
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
```

This is the html: `<div id="div"></div>`

Any help would really be appreciated.

-----------------Edit--------------------
The img has a fixed size so it doesn't fill up the whole browser screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)!

```js
div.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  console.log(e.layerX, e.layerY)
}, false)
```

```css
#div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px black dotted
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the position inside a specific element, you can use:

```
let x = event.clientX;
let y = event.clientY;
```

If you wonder where does `event` come from:

```
document.querySelector("#div").addEventListener("click",(event)=>{
  let x = event.clientX;
  let y = event.clientY;
});
```

And then you can do whatever you want with `x` and `y`.

**Look at an example:**

```js
document.querySelector("#div").addEventListener("click",(event)=>{
  console.log(`x: ${event.clientX}, y:${event.clientY}`);
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;padding:0;
}

#div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```